# Appium is looking for java in the wrong directory

Tags: java, appium

I've finally gotten all the system variables and everything setup, now I've come across a certification error. This is the error when I try to create an appium session:

```
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not sign with default certificate. Original error Command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin\java.exe' not found. Is it installed?
```

JAVA_HOME is not setup to that path though, it's setup to`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath`, where java.exe is located. There is no bin directory. I presume Appium uses JAVA_HOME to determine where to locate java.exe, but it's not looking at the pathway I have setup.

This is my variable for reference:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

NOTE: This is not resolved by running Appium as admin

Edit: Added outputs from cmd to demonstrate no bin.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath>ls
java.exe  javaw.exe  javaws.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath>cd bin
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java>ls
javapath  javapath_target_1290878406
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java>cd bin
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

As you can see, there is no bin directory in either Java or javapath. But java.exe is in javapath.

javapath_target is identical to javapath (same outputs)

Comment: Appium will look  for bin directory under JAVA_HOME. With default Java installation, the bin folder should have been created.

Comment: No bin folder was created. Java.exe is within the javapath folder. I have edited the above to demonstrate this